# MYSQL Select, where rows exists

Tags: mysql, select

I have a Mysql Database and tables with the structure:

1. Table 'photos' - ID, Name
2. Table 'photos_tags' - Key, Photo_ID, Tag

My goal is to select all photos, which has one tag (it's not a problem) and more tags at once.

I've tried this query, but it's not work

```
SELECT photos.id FROM photos, photos_tags WHERE photos.id = photos_tags.photo_id AND (tag = 'cute' OR tag = 'cool')
```

The main problem - this query will select both photos with one of these tags or with two of them. But i need only photos with two these tags at one photo.

Can you help me please? I'm new at MySQL

**UPDATE:** May be there is a better way to organize this schema? My current realization has 'tags' text-field right in table 'photos'. And I use FIND_IN_SET to make a select. But my table has about 1.5M rows - and some queries are very slow.

Comment: My table schema above is very simplyfied - table 'photos' contain some more data like 'user_id'. In the output I need 'id' and 'user_id' - two columns form table 'photos'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "relational division" problem and there are several ways to solve.

One way is with two `EXISTS` subqueries:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM photos AS p
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM photos_tags AS pt
        WHERE p.id = pt.photo_id 
          AND pt.tag = 'cute'
      )
 AND  EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM photos_tags AS pt
        WHERE p.id = pt.photo_id 
          AND pt.tag = 'cool'
      ) ;
```

Another with two joins (assuming that the `photo_tags` table has a unique constraint on `(photo_id, tag_id)`, i.e. no photo can been tagged with the same tag twice):

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM photos AS p
  JOIN photos_tags AS pt1
    ON  p.id = pt1.photo_id 
    AND pt1.tag = 'cute'
  JOIN photos_tags AS pt2
    ON  p.id = pt2.photo_id 
    AND pt2.tag = 'cool' ;
```

One more way is @Abhik's answer, with one join and `GROUP BY`.

You can see a few more ways (more than 13) in this awesome answer: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879). Not all of them will work in MySQL as the question is for Postgres but the problem is identical.

Strictly speaking - and if there is a `FOREIGN KEY` from `photo_tags` to `photos` - the `photos` table can be removed from all the above queries. You can return the `photo_id` instead. But I guess you may want more columns from the `photo` table in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be `group by` and `having` something as

```
select
p.id
from photos p
join  photos_tags pt on pt.photo_id = p.id
where pt.tag in ('cute','cool')
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2 ;
```